# changing file creation date by subtracting 4:00 hours

Tags: linux, shell

I have a file in `c:/users/text.txt`
This `text.tx`t have a file creation date, how to get that `text.txt` creation date and subtract -4:00 using shell script

```
last_update=$(stat -c "%n %y" $file)
```

this statement is giving me the file creation date. How can i subtract -4:00 from it?

for suppose lets say `text.txt` file was created at `04/04/2019 4:00`, i want to change that to `04/04/2019 12:00`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`%y` is not creation but last modification date.

Get the date as seconds since Epoch and subtract 4 hours from it, convert it to human readable form using `date`, change access and modification times of a file using `touch`:

```
$ stat file
  File: file
  Size: 0               Blocks: 0          IO Block: 4096   regular empty file
Device: b31ch/45852d    Inode: 65386       Links: 1
Access: (0600/-rw-------)  Uid: (10138/ u0_a138)   Gid: (10138/ u0_a138)
Access: 2019-04-04 12:34:56.172954982 +0300
Modify: 2019-04-04 12:34:56.172954982 +0300
Change: 2019-04-04 12:34:56.172954982 +0300
 Birth: -
$
$ stat -c '%y' file
2019-04-04 12:34:56.172954982 +0300
$ stat -c '%Y' file
1554370496
$ date -d @$(( $(stat -c '%Y' file) - 4*60*60 ))
Thu Apr  4 08:34:56 +03 2019
$ touch -d "$( date -d @$(( $(stat -c '%Y' file) - 4*60*60 )) )" file
$
$ stat file
  File: file
  Size: 0               Blocks: 0          IO Block: 4096   regular empty file
Device: b31ch/45852d    Inode: 65386       Links: 1
Access: (0600/-rw-------)  Uid: (10138/ u0_a138)   Gid: (10138/ u0_a138)
Access: 2019-04-04 08:34:56.000000000 +0300
Modify: 2019-04-04 08:34:56.000000000 +0300
Change: 2019-04-04 12:37:14.492954929 +0300
 Birth: -
```

See [stat(1)](https://linux.die.net/man/1/stat), [date(1)](https://linux.die.net/man/1/date), and [touch(1)](https://linux.die.net/man/1/touch) for further information.

Comment: $ touch -d "$( date -d @$(( $(stat -c '%Y' file) - 4*60*60 )) )" file
can we store this in a variable and echo the statment?

Comment: ok, I got the output. Tue, Apr 02, 2019  7:00:09 PM

now i need to store this data into a database column which has date type variable. But it is throwing me this error " a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected" do i need to convert this string to to_date or something. if so how ?

Comment: i am using touch -d "$( date -d @$(( $(stat -c '%Y' file) - 4*60*60 )) )" file statement it is giving me Tue, Apr 02, 2019  7:00:09 PM as output is there anyway i get the output as 04/02/2019  7:00:09 PM, and i dont want the TUE day

Comment: @johnmathew see the link I gave to `date` manual, there is an option for specifying the output format

Comment: @johnmathew and you need to know that I'm not obliged to help you any further then answering your original question. so, you either ask another question about this *store data into a database* thing or learn how to do it on your own